# Unrecognized command line option "-fno-objc-arc"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I had over 200 errors in my Xcode project and found that my problem had to do with ARC being enabled. I followed the advice found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) to use the flag `-fno-objc-arc`. Now I am down to only 7 errors, but one of them is in my prefix.pch which is my prefix header for all source files, and says:

```
unrecognized command line option "-fno-objc-arc"
```

Any ideas? I'm using mac 10.6.8, ios sdk 4.3 and xcode 3.2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 3.2.6 may not recognize the flag. From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit
>   applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not
>   supported in OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

You could try installing Xcode 4 and adding this build setting to Xcode 3:

```
CC = /Applications/Xcode4/Developer/usr/bin/clang
```

(path may be different). I think you need at least Snow Leopard for Xcode 4.

Comment: 4.2 seemed to solve it. Thanks! Still haven't gotten the code to work, but at least all those annoying errors are gone. I'll accept it.